# Split file .txt to fill in Datatable C#

Tags: c#

i need help,
i have file txt like below :

```
Jhonathan   Car   17000
Tony        Bike   4000
Mika        Home  20000
```

then i want load this file .txt to datatable with split(' '), i do create code like below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("COL1"); dt.Columns.Add("COL2"); dt.Columns.Add("COL3");
string[] aa = File.ReadAllLines(txtFileName);
       foreach (var item in aa)
   {
       DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
       dr[0] = item.ToString();
       dt.Rows.Add(dr);
   }
   dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
```

}

and i hope the result was like below:
True Result:

```
COL1       | COL2   | COL3 
----------------------------     
Jhonathan  | Car    |17000
Tony       | Bike   |4000
Mika       | Home   |20000
```

but the result from my code  not as expected, and the result was like below :
Failed Result:

```
 COL1                   | COL2    | COL3 
-------------------------------------------     
 Jhonathan  Car   17000 |         |
 Tony       Bike  4000  |         |
 Mika       Home  20000 |         |
```

so how to split for result like true result.
Thx :-)

Comment: the space between your words may not be a `space` caracter (which is in Unicode `U+0020`), but for example a `tab` caracter (which is in Unicode `U+0009`)

Comment: This seems a basic "use Substring" problem.

Comment: If there a variable spaces between columns could be a problem: what about a name like `Jhon Tiberius kirk           Enterprise      90000`

Comment: Looks like the speparators are tabs. So a simple var fields = line.Split('\t'); will do. Please tell us what the spearators are or if the file has fixed length fields!!

Comment: Sorry "James' not jhon

Comment: so i want result just simple, between space one and next space consider as columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather *extract* the routine into a *method* that converts kind of CSV (in your case is tabulation separated file) into table:

```
private static DataTable FileToTable(String fileName) {
  DataTable result = new DataTable();

  foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName)) {
    DataRow row = result.NewRow();

    //TODO: you may want tabulation ('\t') separator as well as space
    String[] items = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // Columns adjusting: you don't need exactly 3 columns  
    for (int i = result.Columns.Count; i < items.Length; ++i) 
      result.Columns.Add(String.Format("COL {0}", i + 1));

    row.ItemArray = items;
    result.Rows.Add(row);
  }

  return result;
}

...

dataGridView3.DataSource = FileToTable(txtFileName);
```

Comment: @General-Doomer: No, the new columns are added *if and only if* the actual data read (`items`) has more items than table (`result`) has columns. Yes, the sample is separated by spaces (' ') now, but often '\t' is used, that's why I've put "...you may want…"

Comment: Great, this best way,
Thanks u Mr. Dmitry Bychenko

Answer (score 4):

**Regex solution**

```
// regular expression for split row:
Regex parser = new Regex(@"\s+");

// modified code (replace with your file path)
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("COL1"); dt.Columns.Add("COL2"); dt.Columns.Add("COL3");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Temp\text.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    string[] words = parser.Split(line);
    dr[0] = words[0];
    dr[1] = words[1];
    dr[2] = words[2];
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

**Fixed string mask solution**

```
// fixed length mask (number of charachers for each field except last field)
int[] mask = { 12, 6 };
int maskLength = mask.Length;

// modified code (replace with your file path)
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("COL1"); dt.Columns.Add("COL2"); dt.Columns.Add("COL3");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Temp\text.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maskLength; pos += mask[i++])
    {
        dr[i] = line.Substring(pos, mask[i]).Trim();
    }
    dr[maskLength] = line.Substring(pos).Trim();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: I think it is a bad idea. His format seems to be "fixed length" format. You are using instead a CSV where comma is space. What happens if there is a `Mac Arthur` that has a bike?

Comment: @General-Doomer just put this in a `for` loop and everyone is happy

Comment: You are splitting at white space instead ot tabs. Let the name contain a space and your code breaks..

Comment: You are still making assumptions, this time about fixed length. The OP should giva a clear indication what the actual separators (if any) are..

Comment: i do this code but, i found error like this "Argument 1:cannot convert from string[] to string "

Comment: @all, so how the best way ?

Comment: @ Muhammad: __You__ need to give us the correct info!

Comment: loop head should be: `for(int i = 0; i < maskLength; pos += mask[i], i++) {`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < maskLength; pos += mask[i++])` is corrent too.

Comment: I know it's correct, but stay away from nested incrementors and such